# Java - Generic, Factory Class

Tags: java, generics

Here is a Java code structure:

```
public interface MyBaby<T> {...}

public class A implements MyBaby<Foo> {...}

public class B implements MyBaby<Boo> {...}

public Class Foo {...}

public Class Boo {...}

public class MyFactory {

  ...
  public synchronized static MyFactory getInstance() {...}

  public MyBaby<?> getMyBaby(BabyType type) {...}
}
```

The above code structure is working with a little problem. To have an instance, I need to do a down casting such as

```
MyBaby<Foo> baby = (MyBaby<Foo>) MyBabyFactory.getInstance().getMyBaby(BabyType.CUTE);
```

How to change the code so that the down casting isn't needed?

Comment: Basically, you can't. Your factory creates instances based on an enum. There is no relationship between your enum and the `<Foo>`-iness of the result, so there is no way for the compiler to know whether it's safe, so you have to cast it.

Comment: The enum type is used to tell the factory which class instance to have. If the enum type is the problem, can you change it to something else to work around it?

Comment: I understand that. We understand that. But the compiler does not understand that. The enum is not the problem really. The problem is the relation between the argument and the result which is not understood by the type system.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a `Class` object like this.

```
public <T> MyBaby<T> getMyBaby(Class<T> type) {
    return (MyBaby<T>) (type == Foo.class ? new A() : new B());
}
```

And

```
    MyBaby<Foo> a = MyFactory.getInstance().getMyBaby(Foo.class);  // OK
    MyBaby<Foo> b = MyFactory.getInstance().getMyBaby(Boo.class);  // Compile error
```

Comment: What's the point of a factory if you have to pass it a concrete class? Why is a client calling `MyFactory.getInstance().getMyBaby(Foo.class);` better than `new A()`?

Comment: You're also assuming each input corresponds to precisely 1 generic type - 1 Foo, 1 Boo, etc. What if there are 2 return values that satisfy `MyBaby<Foo>`. The example given is clearly contrived, so you can't make any assumptions based on it.

Comment: @Michael When there are many classes that implement `MyBaby<Foo>`, the factory can choose one of them. That's what it means to use a factory. The factory in my code is just one example.

Comment: what information would it use to choose one of them? At the moment, you pass a BabyType. Suppose CUTE and HAPPY both should return a MyBaby<Foo>, by changing the input to just Foo.class, how would the factory decide?

Comment: In any case, you haven't removed the cast, you've simply moved the cast.